# Does Android have slider view?

Tags: android

I wonder if Android have a slider view either vertical or horizontal? I expect to see slider as basic view.

I notice Android itself use a slider to unlock screen.

Comment: Android has a view which work as a slider. or Android also have scroll views..

Comment: what is the name of this view. please, notice, I dont need page scroll. I need a slider to control for example volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) which seems like what you are looking for (to control volume)

[image]

However this is not the View that is used for the unlock screen. That is called SlidingTab, and is not part of the public APIs but you can find it online if you wish to include it in your own project [Here is the sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/widget/SlidingTab.java). To use it you'll have to copy all of the relevant layouts and drawables out of the SDK and into your project. It seems to me that this would not be a very good View to use for controling the volume though. I don't think it lets you set it to various points along the way, it is more of a binary type thing (either locked or unlocked)

Comment: Thanks Tim ... so do you have any advice to use slider suitable to work like volume control.